# ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I used the following code for a machine learning problem, which I ended up to the error `ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`

I found some similar topics, but actually, I could not find what is the main problem and how I can fix that. I transform the inputs as a NumPy array with a single column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

def regressor():
   
    X_test_new=np.linspace(0,10,100).reshape(100,1)
    prediction=np.array([])
     
    for i in [1,3,6,9]:    
        poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
        X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(11,1))
        linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_train.reshape(11,1))
        prediction = np.concatenate((prediction,linreg.predict(X_test_new)),axis=0)
     
    return prediction
regressor()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PolynomialFeatures` returns `(11, 2)` your code needs `(11, 1)` to run `LinearRegression` fit function. Additionality, I changed `linreg.predict(...)` response shape to get single column for `concatenate` operation.

```py
    for i in [1,3,6,9]:    
        poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
        X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(11,1))[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
        linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_train.reshape(11,1))
        prediction = np.concatenate((prediction,linreg.predict(X_test_new)[:,0]),axis=0)
```